# Create multiple rows from a single row in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, unpivot, powerbi-desktop

I have a sales dataset where, in addition to (`Sale#`) and several foreign keys `ID1`, `ID2`, `ID3`, `ID4` I have up to 3 Invoices (associated with a `Sale#`). E.g. `Invoice#1`, `SaleAmount1`, `Date1`, `Invoice#2`, `SaleAmount2`, `Date2`, `Invoice#3`, `SaleAmount3`, `Date3`;  all as columns.

I need these three invoice information as rows (as shown below ) instead of columns. Any idea how can it be done in Power BI?

```
Sales#  ID1  ID2 ID3    Invoice#     SaleAmount      Date
----------------------------------------------------------
Sales#1 123 XYZ  A234Y  Invoice#1    SaleAmount1     Date1
Sales#1 123 XYZ  A234Y  Invoice#2    SaleAmount2     Date2
Sales#1 123 XYZ  A234Y  Invoice#3    SaleAmount3     Date3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you just need to unpivot sets of columns.

---

For example, if you select the 3 date columns in the following table

```
Sales#  ID1  Date1     Date2     Date3
-----------------------------------------
Sale#1  123  1/1/2018  1/2/2018  1/3/2018
Sale#2  456  2/2/2018  3/3/2018  4/4/2018
```

and go to Transform > Unpivot Column in the query editor, then you'll get this:

```
Sales#  ID1 Attribute   Value
--------------------------------
Sale#1  123 Date1       1/1/2018
Sale#1  123 Date2       1/2/2018
Sale#1  123 Date3       1/3/2018
Sale#2  456 Date1       2/2/2018
Sale#2  456 Date2       3/3/2018
Sale#2  456 Date3       4/4/2018
```

Then pick which column(s) you want to keep and rename appropriately.

---

You can do the other sets of 3 columns in the same way.